# Why this error when deploying React App on Netlify?

Tags: reactjs, netlify

My react app is working fine on **localhost** but I am getting below **error** when deploying my **React App** on **netlify**. I don't know if  the issue is with *netlify* or *package.json*.

Do I need to update any package versions? How can I fix this error?

My **package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "spice-store",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "E-commerce project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm-run-all --serial dev:build-server dev:build-client dev:server",
    "dev:server": "nodemon --watch build --exec \"node build/bundle.js\"",
    "dev:build-server": "webpack --mode production --config webpack.server.js",
    "dev:build-client": "webpack --mode production --config webpack.client.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "0.16.2",
    "babel-cli": "6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-env": "1.6.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "6.24.1",
    "compression": "1.7.0",
    "concurrently": "3.5.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.5.3",
    "express": "4.15.4",
    "express-http-proxy": "1.0.6",
    "ignore-loader": "^0.1.2",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "nodemon": "1.12.0",
    "npm-run-all": "4.1.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "react-device-detect": "^1.12.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-helmet": "5.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-config": "^5.1.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "2.2.0",
    "serialize-javascript": "1.4.0",
    "style-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "webpack-node-externals": "1.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "isomorphic-style-loader": "^5.1.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
  }
}
```

**Error:**

```
npm
5:00:25 PM: WARN spice-store@1.0.0 No repository field.
5:00:25 PM: added 1219 packages from 552 contributors and audited 1224 packages in 23.833s
5:00:26 PM: 28 packages are looking for funding
5:00:26 PM:   run `npm fund` for details
5:00:26 PM: found 1156 vulnerabilities (387 low, 4 moderate, 765 high)
5:00:26 PM:   run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details
5:00:26 PM: NPM modules installed
5:00:26 PM: Started restoring cached go cache
5:00:26 PM: Finished restoring cached go cache
5:00:26 PM: go version go1.12 linux/amd64
5:00:26 PM: go version go1.12 linux/amd64
5:00:26 PM: Installing missing commands
5:00:26 PM: Verify run directory
5:00:26 PM: Executing user command: npx run dev
5:00:28 PM: npx: installed 5 in 1.487s
5:00:28 PM: Watching /opt/build/repo and all sub-directories not excluded by your .gitignore. Will not monitor dotfiles.
5:00:28 PM: Found & ignored ./node_modules ; is listed in .gitignore
5:00:28 PM: Found & ignored ./package-lock.json ; is listed in .gitignore
5:00:28 PM: Found & ignored ./src/client/DumbComponents/style.css ; has ignored extension
5:00:28 PM: Starting: dev
5:00:28 PM: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
5:00:28 PM:     throw err;
5:00:28 PM:     ^
5:00:28 PM: Error: Cannot find module '/opt/build/repo/dev'
5:00:28 PM:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
5:00:28 PM:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
5:00:28 PM:     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
5:00:28 PM:     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
5:00:28 PM:     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
5:11:37 PM: Canceling deploy
5:11:37 PM: ./webpack.client.js changed
5:11:37 PM: Starting: dev
5:11:37 PM: ./src/helper/renderer.js changed
5:11:37 PM: Starting: dev
5:11:37 PM: ./webpack.server.js changed
5:11:37 PM: Starting: dev
5:11:37 PM: ./src/client/DumbComponents/Home.js changed
5:11:37 PM: Starting: dev
5:11:37 PM: ./src/client/DumbComponents/UserList.js changed
5:11:37 PM: Starting: dev
5:11:37 PM: ./src/client/Components/index.js changed
5:11:37 PM: Starting: dev
5:11:37 PM: ./src/client/client.js changed
5:11:37 PM: Starting: dev
5:11:37 PM: ./src/helper/createStore.js changed
5:11:37 PM: Starting: dev
5:11:37 PM: ./src/client/Components/actions.js changed
5:11:37 PM: Starting: dev
5:11:37 PM: ./src/client/Components/reducers/index.js changed
5:11:37 PM: Starting: dev
5:11:37 PM: ./package.json changed
5:11:37 PM: Starting: dev
5:11:37 PM: (node:1270) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 data listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
5:11:37 PM: ./src/client/DumbComponents/Header.js changed
5:11:37 PM: Starting: dev
5:11:37 PM: ./src/client/Components/reducers/userReducer.js changed
5:11:37 PM: Starting: dev
5:11:37 PM: ./src/client/Routes.js changed
5:11:37 PM: Starting: dev
5:11:37 PM: ./src/client/DumbComponents/NotFound.js changed
5:11:37 PM: Starting: dev
5:11:37 PM: ./src/index.js changed
5:11:37 PM: Starting: dev
5:11:37 PM: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
5:11:37 PM:     throw err;
5:11:37 PM:     ^
5:11:37 PM: Error: Cannot find module '/opt/build/repo/dev'
5:11:37 PM:     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
5:11:37 PM:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
5:11:37 PM:     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
5:11:37 PM:     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
5:11:37 PM:     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
5:11:38 PM: ./public/bundle.js changed
5:11:38 PM: Starting: dev
5:11:38 PM: path.js:1077
5:11:38 PM:         path = process.cwd();
5:11:38 PM:                        ^
5:11:38 PM: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_cwd
5:11:38 PM:     at Object.resolve (path.js:1077:24)
5:11:38 PM:     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:269:32)
5:11:38 PM:     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:623:3)
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're asking, mostly because you don't use any punctuation.

Comment: I don't understand what you are doing, but did you try to find who and why requires `/opt/build/repo/dev`?